# Is there an generally positive / appraisal / emotion boundary?

Tags: computational-linguistics, reference-request, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a dataset for an NLP task connected with sentiment analysis. While thinking on word roles in composing of the overall sentiment and marking particular as being positive/negative, we came across to three different situations:

- word is considered generally positive: food, sleep, health, chocolate, help, politeness, etc;
- word has an appraisal role: respectful, beneficial, responsible, objective *(adj.)*, strong, useful;
- word is emotionally charged: unforgettable, to admire, happy, magnificent, impressive.

Are there **papers and/or research** on the subject? I am looking for a formalized differentiation between those classes of positive/negative words.

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question as I'm unfamiliar with sentiment analysis, but would you consider these discrete categories, or are they on a continuous scale?

Comment: @WavesWashSands I have observed those categories having quite a solid boundary between each other. But within each category you can definitely put them onto a continuous scale.